# Automatically accessing a route periodically in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, request

I am writing a node/express app that uses the request module get the json data from a url when a route is hit. Also I want to continuously get the data without hitting the reload button from the browser.Is there a way to automatically access the route periodically.

Answer (score 1):

You can have Javascript in the browser that uses [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to repeatedly call a function that makes an Ajax call to your server, fetches new data from your server and then inserts it into the page.

If you just want you page to reload automatically, you can use the [meta refresh tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta).  Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.mozilla.org/">
```

Or, if your question is really about how to you just regular do some operation in node.js, then you can just use `setInterval()` within node.js to call some function every xxx ms.

```
// execute a function every 5 seconds
setInterval(function() {
     // do something here
}, 5000);
```

If you want the code that is execute regularly to be the same code that a route uses, then put that code in a function and call that function from both the interval timer and from your route.  To fully automate an actual route call, you'd have to make a request to your own http server that would create the request and response objects for you, but that is probably not what you really need to do.

Comment: I have used that code for a router in the function and set an interval, however I have to reload  the route manually. Actually the route does not display a html page due to which I cannot use the meta refresh tag , however the route is just used to get json values from a url and use the value. Since the route does not use a html page. So how do i automatically redirect to a route . Is there a solution similar to  the res.redirect or res.send for redirecting to a specific route.

Comment: @jba065 - redirect what to a route?  I really don't understand what you're trying to do.  Please describe better what you are trying to accomplish.  The only thing you can redirect on the server is an incoming request and you would do that with `res.redirect(...)` which will then set the location header in the response and set the response status to a 3xx status.